# European Latex document class style for math papers

Tags: document-classes

I have seen the latex math paper style used in this linked article: https://arxiv.org/abs/1907.01473v1, many times, however I am not sure what document class can be used to generate this style; the closest I can find is the `paper` document style which is not quite right.  Does anyone happen to know what latex document class is?

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  The page at arXiv for this paper offers "other formats", which is a zip file containing the tex source and a number of eps files.  Looking into the tex file, one finds this at the top: `\documentclass{iopart}`.

Comment: If I remember correctly, [ntgclass](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/ntgclass) and [koma-script](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) classes were designed for a more European look than standard classes.